# TYPO3 add and implement action for news extension

Tags: php, typo3, tx-news

In my Configuration\TCA\Overrides\tx_news_domain_model.php I add option to select field like this:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['switchableControllerActions']['newItems']['News->gallery'] = 'Gallery view';
```

In my ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['classes']['Controller/NewsController'][] = 'news_extender';
```

In my extension

```
namespace Vendor\NewsExtender\Controller\NewsController;

class NewsController extends \GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsContoller {

    public function galleryAction()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

I get an error: **An action "galleryAction" does not exist in controller "GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsController"** So my guess is no override of actual NewsController happens. 
My question is if it is possible to add new action to the controller the way I do (`['Controller/NewsController'][]`)? If not, can I achieve this other way? If so provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly i did to fix it, but as i did my research i found out that my path to controller was wrong, after changing it i spend few more hours clearing cache from BE and reinstalling extension with no result. After adding line `function listAction() {}` to my NewsController i finally got an error 
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsController::listAction() in D:\live_system\typo3\typo3_src\typo3temp\Cache\Code\news\tx_news_controller_newscontroller.php on line 618`. After clearing **Typo3temp/Cache** manually again and removing `listAction`from my controller all works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first code must go into a ext_localconf file. Please upload full code to eg github.com to take a look as in general it looks good

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is no more code except **ext_emconf.php** file and `if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');` parts.  I changed location of first part to ext_localconf as you suggested, changed namespace from `Vendor\NewsExtender\Controller\NewsController` to `Vendor\NewsExtender\Controller` and changed extension key to `newsextender` with no success.